# Drop Down list Causing Full Post Back With a Weird Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I used a drop down list inside a update panel.i set the required condition's but it still causing a full post back. i searched and tried everything thing which i got but it still stick to the error.

When i do the selected index change it cause full page post and show a error(by fire Bug)

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:`                                       `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument` `Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in` `configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes,` `this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate` `from the server control that originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected,` `use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.' when calling method`: `[nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]`

here is my Code

---

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" 
 runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true">
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

**Update Panel Code**

---

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"  >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCity" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCity_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        Width="200px">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="Pin Code"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPinCode" runat="server" Height="20px" ReadOnly="True" ToolTip="Pin Code"
                                        Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TxtPinCode_TextBoxWatermarkExtender" runat="server"
                                        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TxtPinCode" WatermarkCssClass="WaterMark" WatermarkText="XXXXXX">
                                    </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVINCODE" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtarea"
                                        ErrorMessage="Pin Code Required" Text="*">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" Height="24px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlstate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                        ToolTip="State" Width="200px">
                                        <asp:ListItem>State</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLCity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Please help me out with this one

i Tried this scenario also but this doesn't work also.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(DDLCity.UniqueID.ToString());
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(txtarea.UniqueID.ToString());
        ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(ddlstate.UniqueID.ToString());

        base.Render(writer);

    }
```

Comment: Sometimes we `Enable/Disable` the `Page Level Permission` for `Ajax` in `Web.Config`. Do you have any setting for `location tag` in `web.config` for this page?

Comment: had the same problem using ACT 2.0 with code compiled for .net 4.0, check versions.

Comment: ACT 3.5 and .net 3.5 Frame Work

Comment: @PankajGarg Yeah it There but not for this Page

Comment: Is there any JavaScript that is changing the values of the dropdown list after the page is loaded?

Comment: @Black_Crown Then you need to add it for this page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Location Tag` settings for this page which will give the permission to execute the event `asynchronously`.

For more information Please check **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016768/726802)** and **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbkh9s7.aspx)**

Comment: i found an another way to do this by callbackinterfaces.Thanks for consideration

Comment: i tried but it's not worked in my case.May be by some other problem which i not able to find out

Comment: Please add your own answer, If your own views worked and accept it. This can be usefult for future users.